# Problem with cookies from Ajax call in Webworks for Smartphone

Tags: php, ajax, widget, cordova, blackberry-webworks

i have an app written in Html and Javascript. This app works fine on my android phone.

Now i use the same codes with webworks but i have problem, that cookies from my ajax call is not set back to the browser on real device (9300 OS6) but somehow works on Simulator (9800 OS6, 9300 OS6).

Does anyone have the same problem and know how to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I look at this issue your having from a standard non mobile website. Let's presume:

1. Page A sets a cookie in javascript, example `$.cookie('cookieKey', 'A');`
2. Page A calls some ajax to Page B
3. Page B sets the cookie in javascript, example `$.cookie('cookieKey', 'B');`
4. Page A's knowledge of the cookieKey is still a value of 'A'. Normally a cookie set on Page A, will stay as such until the page is reloaded/refreshed. So you probably should after your ajax call/run:
5. `window.location.reload();`

The same is true whether your setting the cookie with php or javascript. Your ajax set cookie will not be available until the parent caller is refreshed on the network.

Can you rule out that this is not the issue you are having?